# "@" is not valid input at this position MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm following tutorial of dev.mysql and I'm trying to set the default to all assigned roles for each account created earlier so I tried to use this statement:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html

```
SET DEFAULT ROLE ALL TO
  'dev1'@'localhost',
  'read_user1'@'localhost',
  'read_user2'@'localhost',
  'rw_user1'@'localhost';
```

but I couldn't because of this error "@" is not valid input at this position for this server version,expecting ';'

I'm using workbench 8.0

Comment: Did you try to set the role one user at a time ?

Comment: yes, I tried it

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the MySQL grammar used by MySQL Workbench. See [the code on Github](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLParser.g4#L1805). The relevant rule here is:

```
role:
    roleIdentifierOrText (AT_SYMBOL textOrIdentifier)?
;
```

`AT_SYMBOL` should in fact be `AT_SIGN_SYMBOL`. I'll fix this.